# Futex wakeup after thread exit

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, futex

I have `strace`'d a correctly working program to compare with a faulty one. In the correct one, I have two threads (using pthreads) with one waiting for the other with regular `pthread_join`. Under the hoods I can see that the waiting (primary) thread waits on a futex (looking into sources and verifying with GDB the address matches `&pd->tid`). The part I don't understand is that there's no matching `FUTEX_WAKE` on this address when the second thread exits:

```
2579217 futex(0x7fe28bfff910, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 2579218, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY <unfinished ...>
...
2579218 madvise(0x7fe28bf00000, 1024000, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
2579218 exit(0)                         = ?
2579217 <... futex resumed>)            = 0
2579218 +++ exited with 0 +++
2579217 exit_group(0)
```

I have suspected the [robust futex ABI](https://docs.kernel.org/locking/robust-futex-ABI.html) to leave the wakeup to kernel, but the list seems to be empty. I think that it would make sense to wakeup (or segfault?) waiting threads if the memory with futex word gets unmapped but this does not seem to be the case. What makes kernel wake up this primary thread?

Comment: The kernel simply writes 0 to the TID and then makes thread 1 return from the `futex` syscall (which is blocking). There is no need for any `FUTEX_WAKE`, the kernel itself wakes up the waiter.

Comment: `strace` will not show the `FUTEX_WAKE` done by the kernel on behalf of the exiting thread. The wake-up is done by the call to `do_futex()` (or `sys_futex()` for older kernels) from the `mm_release()` function in "kernel/fork.c".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `mm_release()`, that's what I was looking for (I need to compare why this behaviour does not work in the other program).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints in comments I was able to figure out what's happening, so only to explain things a bit further: the wakeup is documented in `clone` function through the `CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID` flag and can be set or changed later during the life of the thread using the `set_tid_address` syscall.

One more thing that helped me debugging is [trace from bcctools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/trace_example.txt) - I was able to debug kernel through

```
sudo trace-bpfcc -K 'mm_release(struct task_struct *tsk, struct mm_struct *mm) "%x %d", tsk->clear_child_tid, mm->mm_users.counter'
```